# Randomly display values from an array excluding value in index 0 in flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter

I am a beginner in flutter. I was building an app  as a part of learning and came across this confusion. I have an array with some names and I wanna display those names randomly on button press. I left the index 0 value as  null  so that every time the app loads no names are displayed. The problem is when i press the button this null value is also displaying. Please help me.

```
class _FoodieState extends State<Foodie> {
List<String> foodieName = ['','foodie1', 'foodie2', 'foodie3', 'foodie4', 'foodie5','foodie6','foodie7'];
int foodieNumber=0;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
home: Scaffold(
backgroundColor: Colors.white,
body: Center(
child: Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
children: <Widget>[
CircleAvatar(
radius: 120.0,
backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/burger.jpg'),
),
ElevatedButton(
child: Text('Who will buy today\'s\ lunch ?'),
style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
primary: Colors.yellow[800],
onPrimary: Colors.white,
shape: const BeveledRectangleBorder(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
),
textStyle: TextStyle(
fontFamily: 'Rancho',
fontSize: 35,
color: Colors.grey,
),
),
onPressed: () {
setState(() {
foodieNumber=Random().nextInt(foodieName.length);
});

},
),
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
child: Text(
foodieName[foodieNumber],
style: TextStyle(
fontFamily: 'Pacifico',
fontSize: 30,
color: Colors.red,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
),
),
],
),
),
),
);
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please prettify your code listing a little bit for future readers of your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesnt display first index:

```
foodieNumber=Random().nextInt(foodieName.length - 1) + 1;
```